# Trouble understanding the proof that the strictly full triangulated subcategory of objects computing the right derived functor is saturated

Tags: derived-functors, triangulated-categories

I am trying to understand the proof of Lemma [05T0](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05T0) of the Stacks Project. Before explaining the lemma, I will give the context that explains the title of this post.

Let $F:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D}'$ be a triangulated functor between triangulated categories and let $S$ be a saturated multiplicative system compatible with the triangulated structure on $\mathcal{D}$ (Situation [05S8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05S8)). To define the derived functors, we are using Definition [05S9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05S9) for the action on objects and Lemma [05SA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05SA) for the action on morphisms (I think this is Deligne's definition of the derived functors in [exposé XVII of SGA4](http://www.normalesup.org/%7Eforgogozo/SGA4/17/17.pdf), although I haven't read the exposé). By definition, one says that an object $X$ of $\mathcal{D}$ *computes* $RF$ if $RF$ is defined at $X$ and the canonical morphism $F(X)\to RF(X)$ is an isomorphism (Definition [05SX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05SX)).

The full subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ of objects computing $RF$ is strictly full. By Lemmas [05SZ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05SZ) and [05QX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05QX), it is a strictly full triangulated subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$. Lemma [05T0](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05T0) asserts that, in addition, it is [saturated](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05RB).

To understand the proof, the first problem I have is with “hence $F(X') = F(X) \oplus E$ for some object $E$ of $\mathcal{D}'$ such that $E \to F(X' \oplus Y) \to RF(X'\oplus Y) = RF(X \oplus Y)$ is zero (Lemma [05QU](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05QU)).” I do understand why $F(X)\to F(X')$ having a retraction implies that it must be isomorphic to an inclusion $F(X)\to F(X)\oplus E$ (this is a property of monomorphisms in pre-triangulated categories), but where does the latter condition on the vanishment of $E$ comes from? On the other hand, taking for granted this vanishment condition, I think I understand everything what comes after until “$F(t')\to E$ annihilates $E$” (this last thing I understand too). But why is it that after “it follows that $F$ is essentially constant on $X/S$ with value $F(X)$”?

---

I found an straightforward proof of the result if we assume the additional hypothesis that $RF$ is defined at $X$ or at $Y$ (by the distinguished triangle $X\to X\oplus Y\to Y\xrightarrow{0}X[1]$ and Lemma [05SC](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05SC), this is if and only if $RF$ is defined at *both* $X$ and $Y$. This condition is obtained for free is $\mathcal{D}'$ is Karoubian, [05SD](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05SD)).

Fully spelled out, the following is a proof of “if $X\oplus Y$ computes $RF$ and $RF$ is defined at $X$ and $Y$, then $X$ and $Y$ compute $RF$ too.”

For the proof, one must use the following

> *Exercise.* Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a preadditive category and let $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}:A_1\oplus B_1\to A_2\oplus B_2$ be a morphism in $\mathcal{A}$. If this morphism is an isomorphism, then so are $a:A_1\to A_2$ and $b:B_1\to B_2$.

Suppose then that $RF$ is defined at $X\oplus Y$, $X$ and $Y$ and that $F(X)\oplus F(Y)=F(X\oplus Y)\to RF(X\oplus Y)=RF(X)\oplus RF(Y)$ is an isomorphism (where we have used that $F$ and $RF$ are additive, the latter being shown at the beginning of [05SD](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05SD)). We claim that the morphism $F(X\oplus Y)\to RF(X\oplus Y)$ is of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$, where $a:F(X)\to RF(X)$ and $b:F(Y)\to RF(Y)$ are the canonical maps. By the exercise, we will be done after seeing this.

By Lemma [05SA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05SA), we have a commutative diagram:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(X)@>>> RF(X)\\
@VVV@VVV\\
F(X\oplus Y)@>>> RF(X\oplus Y)\\
@VVV@VVV\\
F(Y)@>>> RF(Y)
\end{CD}
$$

where the left (resp., right) vertical maps are the image of $F$ (resp., of $RF$) of the inclusion of $X$ and projection of $Y$ with respect to $X\oplus Y$. By additivity of $F$ (resp., of $RF$), these maps are inclusion and projection with respect to $F(X\oplus Y)$ (resp., w.r.t. $RF(X\oplus Y)$). By commutativity of the upper square, we deduce that the composite $F(X)\to F(X)\oplus F(Y)\to RF(X)\oplus RF(Y)\to RF(X)$ equals the canonical map $F(X)\to RF(X)$. By commutativity of the outer rectangle, we deduce that the composite $F(X)\to F(X)\oplus F(Y)\to RF(X)\oplus RF(Y)\to RF(Y)$ is zero. Changing $X\leftrightarrow Y$, the analogous properties follows for $Y$.

---

If only there was an alternative way of proving that $RF$ is defined at $X$ provided that $RF$ computed $X\oplus Y$, this proof idea would work. However, I am not sure if there is an easier way of seeing this than what the proof of [05T0](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05T0) does (and which I don't understand).